# Can't get Outer Dimensions of Circle with stroke-width, but Chrome can

Tags: javascript, svg

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Lh3Um/22/ for the demo w/complete problem description.

Briefly: I can't figure out how Chrome debugger is reporting '46 x 46' for the circle element with a radius of 20px and a stroke of 5px in my svg.

Neither `getBBox()` nor `getBoundingClientRect()` gives me that value. Oddly, in this case `getBoundingClientRect()` reports the same dimension as `getBBox()`; before it's always reported "45 x 45" - not 100% accurate, but at least closer to what I want.

Can anyone tell me how Chrome is getting the "46 x 46" dimension, and if I can make that call in javascript? I don't care about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

As W3C SVG spec [4.5.23 Interface SVGLocatable](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable), getBBox() should not include stroking, clipping, masking and filter effects.

SVGRect getBBox()

Returns the tight bounding box in current user space (i.e., after application of the ‘transform’ attribute, if any) on the geometry of all contained graphics elements, ***exclusive of stroking, clipping, masking and filter effects***). Note that getBBox must return the actual bounding box at the time the method was called, even in case the element has not yet been rendered.